# Delay a notification build (Android)

Tags: android, build, handler, delay, android-notifications

I want to delay the build of the notification to e.g. 1 min, how do I do it? I tried to insert an handler and postDelaying it but I get multiple errors.

```
   public void customizedOnClick (View view){
        String ticker = textTicker.getText().toString();
        String title = textTitle.getText().toString();
        String body = textBody.getText().toString();


        notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notification.setTicker(ticker);
        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setContentTitle(title);
        notification.setContentText(body);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        //Builds notification and issues it
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());


    }
```

Comment: What kind of error did you get ?

Comment: This was when I tried to use a handler, but I erased it from the original code.
Error:(59, 33) error: Handler is abstract; cannot be instantiated
Error:(60, 16) error: cannot find symbol method postDelayed(<anonymous Runnable>,int)

Comment: Are you sure you imported the correct `Handler`. There is an abstract handler in the `java.util.logging` package. You want the one in `android.os`

Comment: you probably have the wrong import

Comment: It was the wrong import, but now I don't know where to put the onClick. Please look in the answer below. @Knossos

Comment: @Knossos can you please help me with another question? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498565/datetime-does-not-show-up

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks for the help, can you also please help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498565/datetime-does-not-show-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to import the correct Handler:

> import android.os.Handler;

Create the handler and a runnable. The runnable will be your code that will execute after the delay.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(); 

private NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
private static final int uniqueID = 12345;
private EditText textTicker;
private EditText textTitle;
private EditText textBody;

public void customizedOnClick (View view) {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(textTicker.getText() 
          || TextUtils.isEmpty(textTitle.getText())
          || TextUtils.isEmpty(textBody.getText()){
        Log.e("NotificationClick", "A TextView was empty or null");
        return;
    }

    String ticker = textTicker.getText().toString();
    String title = textTitle.getText().toString();
    String body = textBody.getText().toString();

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
           .setTicker(ticker);
           .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
           .setContentTitle(title);
           .setContentText(body);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 20 * 1000); //twenty seconds delay
 }

 private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        NotificationManager nm =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());
    }
 };
```

Comment: It was the wrong handler class, but I do not understand how to set up the onClick now?

Comment: yourview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do something
            }
        });

Comment: Thank you so much, it was wrongly formatted so I posted a new answer, or should I just edit yours?

Comment: They were pretty much the same. But I edited it. Glad you figured it out

Comment: I made a few changes too. Null check that would be good for you to add .

Comment: Great, deleted mine answer now. Thanks once again! 
Can you please help with another question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498565/datetime-does-not-show-up

Answer (score -1):

Just note that the use of the Handler is'nt always precise, because the "Time spent in deep sleep will add an additional delay to execution". So if you want a precise amount of time (like for a game energy bar) you should choose something else than a Handler.